# How to dynamically add custom rds parameters on parameter groups for postgressql using terraform?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform

I have used the below code to edit the values of postgressql parameters on parameter groups on aws using terraform.

main.tf

```
resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "education" {
  name   = "education"
  family = var.family

  parameter {
    apply_method = "immediate"
    name         = "name_of_parameter_1"
    value        = "value for parameter 1"
  }
  parameter {
    apply_method = "immediate"
    name         = "name_of_prameter_2"
    value        = "value_for_parameter_2"
  }

}

resource "aws_db_instance" "education" {
  identifier             = "education"
  instance_class         = "db.t3.micro"
  allocated_storage      = 5
  engine                 = "postgres"
  engine_version         = "14.1"
  username               = "edu"
  password               = var.db_password
  db_subnet_group_name   = aws_db_subnet_group.education.name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.rds.id]
  parameter_group_name   = aws_db_parameter_group.education.name
  publicly_accessible    = true
  skip_final_snapshot    = true
}
```

code snippet from variables.tf

```
variable "family" {
  description = "The family of the DB parameter group"
  type        = string
}
```

How can I refactor the above code so I can add the parameters in a list on a terraform.tfvars file and dynamically load them on aws_db_parameter_group instead of hardcoding them there like on the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list is the wrong data structure to use for this. You need both parameter names and parameter values in the .tfvars file, and that would naturally be represented by a [map](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/map).

A `terraform.tfvars` file could look like this:

```
rds_parameters = {
  param1 = "param 1 value",
  param2 = "param 2 value",
  param3 = "param 3 value",
}
```

The input variable in `variables.tf` would look like this:

```
variable "rds_parameters " {
  description = "The map of DB parameter names and values"
  type        = map(string)
}
```

Finally, you would use a Terraform [dynamic block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) to create DB parameters from that map:

```
resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "education" {
  name   = "education"
  family = var.family

  dynamic "parameter " {
    for_each = var.rds_parameters
    content {
      apply_method = "immediate"
      name = setting.key
      value = setting.value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It works but I think we need a map on rds_parameters..reason is that we may want to pass different values for the apply_method for each parameter. My solution was to use a list of maps instead of map for rds_parameters.